# Django unique filtering

Tags: python, django

Take the following two models:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    #...

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    date_made = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today())
    #...
```

## goal

Be able to get all `Parent` instances (no doubles) dependent on a query in the `Child` instances.

## what I have

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
a_while_ago = now - datetime.timedelta(days=20)

recent = Child.objects.filter(date_made__gte=a_while_ago)

#I would like, in the most efficient way, to be able to get all the unique
#parents of the children in `recent`. I am completely stumped here...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to filter directly on the `Parent` model:

```
parents = Parent.objects.filter(child__date_made__gte=a_while_ago).distinct()
```

You can also use a `values` or `values_list` query on `recent`, but that returns `parent` PKs rather than `parent` instances:

```
parent_pks = recent.values_list('parent', flat=True).distinct()
```

You could then use `in_bulk` to retrieve the actual instances:

```
parents = Parent.objects.in_bulk(parent_pks)
```

I would expect the first to be faster.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot that I could filter directly from the `Parent` model to get stuff on it's children